# EzPLatform kernel class extension

Tags: ezpublish, ezplatform, ibexa

As part of my job, I took over the maintenance of a project based on ezPlatform. ( i'm new on this framework)

In a bundle, I would like to extend the ezuser.php class (myproject/ezpublish_legacy/kernel/classes/datatypes/ezuser/ezuser.php) to add a method to it.

The bundle in question is located at (myproject/src/prestataire/MyBundle/)

What is the procedure to follow?

I tried to write a simple customEzUser which extends ezuser but it does not seems to work.
I tried to register the file in yml files to.